# Очень быстрое движение фигуры sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

У меня есть фигура(квадрат для примера):

```
VertexArray quad(LinesStrip, 5);
 quad[0].position = Vector2f(0, 0);
 quad[1].position = Vector2f(25, 0);
 quad[2].position = Vector2f(25, 25);
 quad[3].position = Vector2f(0, 25);
 quad[4].position = quad[0].position;
```

Я создал класс figure и объявил там публичный метод:

```
    VertexArray drawQuad() {
     VertexArray quad(LinesStrip, 5);
     quad[0].position = Vector2f(0, 0);
     quad[1].position = Vector2f(25, 0);
     quad[2].position = Vector2f(25, 25);
     quad[3].position = Vector2f(0, 25);
     quad[4].position = quad[0].position;
     return quad;
}
```

В приватном поле у меня есть переменные:

```
float x = 0, y = 0;
float moveSpeed = 5;
```

Еще у меня есть метод для перемещения фигуры по нажатию клавиш:

```
    void move(Event &event) {
    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                x -= moveSpeed;
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                x += moveSpeed;
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
                y -= moveSpeed;
            else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down)
                y += moveSpeed;
        }
}
```

И собственно метод для вывода на экран:

```
    void drawQuadWin(RenderWindow &window) {
    Transformable trans;
    trans.setPosition(500, 500);
    trans.move(x,y);
    window.draw(drawQuad(), trans.getTransform());
}
```

Суть проблемы: когда я вызываю 2 метода из класса для отрисовки и движения фигуры, она двигается очень быстро, то-есть при нажатии клавиши вверх, фигура вылетает за границы экрана. Аналогично и с другими направлениями. Но если я не меняя ничего проверну тоже самое в main. В цикле `while(window.isOpen())` нарисую выведу и буду двигать фигуру, все будет работать идеально.Как исправить?

Comment: А скорость `5` не слишком быстрая? Ну и наверное нужна проверка на выход за пределы окна

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup нет, не слишком. Я написал что если я сделаю все в мейне, фигура будет двигаться как нужно, скажем для выхода за пределы мне нужно будет нажать вверх 50 раз.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, скорее всего, не в приведённом коде, а в общем цикле отрисовки -- fps слишком большой. Прочитайте классическую статью и попробуйте использовать циклы оттуда https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/

Comment: Проблема не в фпс. Иначе фигура вела бы себя одинаково, что в мейне, что в другом классе.